How to keep only git-lfs files that are actively used by any branch heads?
Imagine a repo with the following history
| trunk -> LargeFile1.rev0
| trunk -> LargeFile1.rev1
|\ rel  -> LargeFile1.rev1
| trunk -> LargeFile1.rev2
| trunk (head) -> -> LargeFile1.rev3

Note revx is not part of the filename, but a change indicator.
I want to clean up any large files that are not used by any branch heads.
So in this case, keep rev 1 (used by rel head), and rev3, which is current trunk head.
I'm in the process of migrating from svn to git, and want to only move large files that are required to build any branch heads, while pruning the rest from history.
I researched: https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/
By default the HEAD is protected, so just running e.g. '--strip-blobs-bigger-than 5M' would do what I want for trunk, but it doesn't take into account the other branch heads?
